# How to push dynamic values into an array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

This is my array `ARRAY`

```
 ARRAY = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
 var mlength = ARRAY.length;
```

and my variables are

```
 var mname0 = a, var mname1 = b, var mname2 = c, var mname3 = d, var mname4 = e

 var month = JAN;
```

I am trying to push values to array based on `mlength`. I tries the below code but that's not working

```
  for (var i = 0, i < mlength; i++) {
      MARKETS[i].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname+i, month)) || null);
  }
```

That's not working. I am getting an error

How do I push the variables in for loop?

Comment: Error here `for (var i = 0; i < mlength; i++)`. see the `;` and `mname+i` is not going to work. You may need `window["mname"+i]`

Comment: take off the `[i]` it should be like this: `MARKETS.push(...`

Answer (score 2):

`mname+i` will not do what you think it’s doing. Say that `i` is `2`. You might expect `mname+i` to return `c` (the value of variable `mname2`). Instead, what it will actually do is add `mname` (an undefined variable) + `2`, giving a `ReferenceError`.

Your `mname0`, `mname1`, etc. variables should be an array:

`var mname = [a, b, c, d, e];`

And then reference it like this:

`findDataForMonth(mname[i], month)`

Comment: And for further clarification, what you're trying to do is runtime evaluation which would look like this `eval("mnane"+i)` but don't do that. Use for example an array as suggested or an object, much less and neater code too.

Comment: @Nate - then what is the solution for this?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if a, b, c, d... are supposed to be strings or variables. If they should be strings it should read `var mname = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];`

Comment: Using an array should be the solution. There’s obviously more to this than the code that you’ve shown, though. Is there a reason an array won’t work?

Answer (score 0):

Since the values in ARRAY and values of mname vars are the same (just the case is different), you could do the following.

```
var ARRAY = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
var mlength = ARRAY.length;
var month = JAN;
var mnames = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
//OR
//var mnames = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var i = 0; i < mlength; i++) {
    var mname = mnames[i];
    //instead of mname+i just use mname
}
```

Your way:

1) Wrap the below code either in `head` or `body` with no `ready` handlers (such as `window.onload` `dom ready` etc.) as `mname` vars will be local and not avilable in the `window` scope otherwise.

```
var ARRAY = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
var mlength = ARRAY.length;
var mname0 = 'a';
var mname1 = 'b';
var mname2 = 'c';
var mname3 = 'd';
var mname4 = 'e';

for (var i = 0; i < mlength; i++) {
    alert (window['mname'+i]);
}
```

2) If you are to use the code in one of the `ready` handlers, you have 2 options. Either define your `mname` variable with no `var` keyword or prepend `window.` like below.

```
var ARRAY = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
var mlength = ARRAY.length;
mname0 = 'a'; // or window.mname0 = 'a';
mname1 = 'b'; // or window.mname1 = 'b';
mname2 = 'c'; // etc.
mname3 = 'd';
mname4 = 'e';

for (var i = 0; i < mlength; i++) {
    alert (window['mname'+i]);
}
```

Remember, polluitng the global namespace is a bad practice, unless you really need to.

Comment: I cant give like that. I just gave var mname0 = a, var mname1 = b as an example. I need to give mname+i and in the place of i the number must be replaced. this is the requirement

Comment: Sure, I've edited, but you should've been more specific in your question. _I cant give like that_ at the very first attempt of the question helps a lot and save us a lot of time!

Comment: here mnames are variable how can I take it as an array I have mname0, mname1, and so on

Comment: That I understood. But how to push the variables into array like for (var i = 0, i < mlength; i++) {
      MARKETS[i].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname+i, month)) || null);
  }